# How much do laptop model numbering schemes vary between manufacturers?

Tags: laptop

Do they share any conventions, or just make everything up? In particular, how do they usually handle customization?

Comment: Uh, this depends on the manufacturer...

Comment: Bias aside, I believe that, while obviously uninformed, this is a reasonable question to which there are reasonable answers.

Comment: @Shinrai: I figured it depended on the manufacturer, but I didn't know to what extent, whether they shared any conventions or just made everything up. Maybe that would have been a better question?

Comment: That's a much better question, to the extent that I'd vote to reopen if you edited.

Comment: @Shinrai: Is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on the manufacturer. In my experience, HP uses a model number for the general configurations down to a certain level. For instance, any model you can buy as-is from the website or from a store will have a number unique to it's configuration. However, if you customize the system, the model number will revert to the closest major model number and ends with "CTO".

I purchased a DV1000 heavily customized. and it was listed as a DV1000CTO rather than the DV1253 or whatever it may have actually been closer to.

But different manufacturers handle this differently.